# How to remove empty arrays from an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array of arrays which includes some empty arrays. 
Exp. [ [Name1],[Name2],[Name3],[],[] ]

I tried using shift and splice (example code given)

```
function RemoveEmptyArrays(){
  var NameArray = [[Name1],[Name2],[Name3],[],[]];

  for (i = 0; i < NameArray.length; i++) {
      if ( NameArray[i][0] === undefined ) {
         NameArray.splice(  i, 1 );
      }
  }
  Logger.log(arrayvals);
}
```

Desired Output:

```
[ [Name1],[Name2],[Name3] ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve from `[[Name1],[Name2],[Name3],[],[]]` to `[ [Name1],[Name2],[Name3] ]`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
var NameArray = [["Name1"],["Name2"],["Name3"],[],[]];
var res = NameArray.filter(function(e) {return e.length})
console.log(res)
```

#### Modified script:

If your script is modified, how about this modification?

```js
var NameArray = [["Name1"],["Name2"],["Name3"],[],[]];

for (i = NameArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // Modified
  if ( NameArray[i][0] === undefined ) {
    NameArray.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(NameArray);
```

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to do this is using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) from ES6 and then [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

'concat' concatenates arrays to another array, and the spread operator takes an array and passes it to a function as if they were parameters (among other things).

Here's a working fiddle

```js
const arr = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], [] ,[]] ;

const result = [].concat(...arr)

console.warn(result);
```